# How to use shared Preferences on Android?

Tags: java, android, database, preferences, shared

I am creating a very simple application that only has a seek bar that the user can use.
My code looks like this :

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    int number=50;
    SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider);
    sb.setMax(100);
    sb.setProgress(number);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar v, int progress, boolean isUser) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percent);
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%");


}
```

What i want to do is store the seek bars state and when the application is killed and the user opens it again , the last change is displayed on the seek bar and not the default.
So i must use shared preferences on my int number variable? I cant understand how i can do that since when the application starts again the line `int number=50` will be run again , so the value will go to 50 again.

Comment: have you ever searched for the task before asking the question..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this ought to work:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor spe;


    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    spe = sp.edit();


    int number= sp.getInt("seekNum", 50);
    SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider);
    sb.setMax(100);
    sb.setProgress(number);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar v, int progress, boolean isUser) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percent);
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%");


}


@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    spe.putInt("seekNum", sb.getProgress());
    spe.commit();
}
```

Comment: Well i put outside the functions : SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();

    SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider);

so that all my functions can see that but it crashes on run

Answer (score 1):

**StackOverflow is not your research assistant.** The task you are trying to achieve is *ridiculously* simple.

Consult the [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This can be modified for whatever datatype you need:

```
private void loadSettings(){
    if(prefs == null) prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, 0);

    yourString = prefs.getString(YOUR_KEY, ""); 
}
private void saveSettings(){
    if(prefs == null) prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, 0);

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEd = prefs.edit();

    prefsEd.putString(YOUR_KEY, yourString);

    prefsEd.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with both a sharedPreference or the savedInstanceState.

Check out [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

Of course the value to always doing to be 10 in that hardcoded assignment. You'll need to pull that value our of the sharedpref if you decide to go that route.